# How can I limit the number of posts that load in the Facebook Page Plugin?

Tags: facebook, iframe, accessibility, facebook-iframe

The Facebook Page Plugin loads an infinite number of posts, this causes issues for accessibility as there's no way to move beyond the Facebook Page Plugin widget with the keyboard. Is there a way to limit the number of posts that load? Here's the plugin page from FB: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/

Comment: That’s not possible. You are limited to the configuration options mentioned on that page.

Comment: I would recommend providing an anchor link before the plugin that takes the user to an anchor just below the plugin.

Alternatively, let the plugin be collapsed/expanded so you can easily move past it.

Comment: @TobiasChristianJensen would this prevent the user for accessing the content?

Comment: @Dpuiatti Not the way I see it. It just allows the user to skip the block, or with the alternative approach, to hide/show it.